# SocketTimeoutException при потере соединения

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

Почему-то когда меняешь подключение к сети с WiFi на мобильную сеть, или просто при потере соединения и последующем восстановлении, при обновлении данных постоянно возникает **SocketTimeoutException**.

Затем через пару минут бывает проблема исчезает и все снова ок. Также помогает полный перезапуск приложения.

Используется *https* соединение, *retrofit 2.2.0*, коннекты с определенным периодом идут через *rxJava*.

Конечно я уже игрался с разными таймаутами записи, чтения, коннекта, не помогает.

В чем может быть проблема и как избежать? Может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выяснил, что это баг в okHttp 3.6.0, который висит уже несколько месяцев.

Топик и обсуждение на [гитхабе](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3146)

Answer (score 0):

Исключение `SocketTimeoutException` выбрасывается тогда, когда по http был отправлен запрос, но соединение оборвалось и ответ не удалось получить за определенное время. Соединение разрывается при переключении между wifi сетями, либо между wifi и мобильной сетью - это нормальное поведение, лишь небольшая часть новых смартфонов имеет технологию сохранения состояния соединения.

Решение этой проблемы простое: реконнект и повтор запроса. В случае с http - просто повтор запроса, так как коннект устанавливается на уровне протокола.

Comment: Да, это я понимаю. Но суть в другом. Я переключился, у меня появился стабильный интернет, но повторные запросы не проходят в следующие минут 5, всегда возникает эта ошибка (Даже не один запрос, а абсолютно все и разные).  Причем и браузер нормально работает, и другие приложения. После перезапуска самого приложения все становится нормальным.

Comment: Тогда только код смотреть.

Comment: Код вполне себе стандартный, обычный get запрос на Rx.
В ходе проверок заметил, что проявляется только на Android 7.1.1 Lineage 14.1 (OnePlus One). На самсунгах разных версий все хорошо. Больше к сожалению тестовых девайсов нет. С эмуляторами тоже проблем нет. Есть же вероятность, что прошивка косячная?

Comment: Lineage OS еще не стабильна, конечно вероятность есть.